# Mock ZeroMQ Reply in jest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I am using `jest` to unit test a module which uses `ZeroMQ`, very simple:

```
import { Reply } from "zeromq";
import { config } from '../../config';

export class ZeroMQ {
  public sock: Reply;

  constructor() {
    this.sock = new Reply();
  }

  async connect() { 
    await this.sock.bind(`tcp://*:${config.ZeroMQ.ZEROMQ_PORT}`);
  }
}
```

However, I cannot mock the `new Reply()` part, or at least I cannot check that it's called (or that `bind` is called). This is my test class:

```
import { ZeroMQ } from "../../Infrastructure/ZeroMQ/ZeroMQ";
import { Reply } from "zeromq";

jest.mock("zeromq");
jest.mock("../../config", () => ({
    config: {
        ZeroMQ: {
            ZEROMQ_PORT: 5678,
        },
    },
}));

describe("Test zero mq", () => {
    let sut: ZeroMQ;

    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks();
        sut = new ZeroMQ();
    });

    test("Test connect function -> Should call connect on tcp://*:port", async () => {
        await sut.connect();
        expect(Reply.prototype.bind).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
});
```

I also tried mocking like this:

```
jest.mock("zeromq", function () {
    return {
        Reply: jest.fn().mockImplementation(function () {
            this.bind = jest.fn(async (uri: string) => {
                console.log("bind: " + uri);
            });

            return {
                bind: this.bind
            };
        }),
    };
});
```

I read some answers, tried to mock the `zeromq` module without the function, changed the import order, spied on the `bind` function... I am kinda new to `jest` coming from a .NET background, and I cannot seem to manage this.

The subject under test seems to be using the original class, not the mocked one.

Edit: If I modify the `beforeEach` call like this, I can assign the mock socket, but it should be private actually (but it may add some context):

```
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks();
        sut = new ZeroMQ();
        sut.sock = new Reply();
    });
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What behaviour of your class are you actually trying to test? That isn't the whole class is it?

Comment: I'm just trying to check if `sock.bind` is called once. The class has a couple more functions but once I am able to mock this one, the others are trivial. There's not more relevant code to this question in particular.

Comment: This seems a bit strange. You really want to be testing the behaviours of your classes, rather than those of third party libraries. In doing so, you'd of course be making a connection. Further, you really don't want to be mocking third party libraries, as your tests will give you a false sense of security then - they can pass, but don't tell you whether you've integrated the library properly. Further, the library could change in some way and your tests wouldn't fail.

Comment: I'm not testing the behavior of the library, the only thing I want to test is that my class effectively creates a new `Reply` socket and binds to it. So if I change the code in the future and forget to call `bind`, it would fail. It is a very simple case but verifying that your mocks are called is standard practice in unit testing. My use case is exactly the one described in the docs: https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks but the library class is not the `default export`, it is the only difference.

Comment: But surely you need that socket to do _something_. Why aren't you testing that something? Sure, you can mock whatever you like but mocking things that you don't have control over isn't a good idea for reasons I've mentioned above.

Comment: Yes, the socket then will call `send` method, but it won't work also because of the same exact reasons. I'd need to mock the `send` function and check that it's called. It is the exact same thing as checking that the `bind` function is called.

Comment: I'd stress again, don't mock those - use the real thing. Do you already have tests that use the real thing? If not, why not?

Comment: Yes, but those are a totally different type of tests, they are integration tests and I am trying to write unit tests.

Comment: Yes, but if you have integration tests covering the functionality to make sure it works, why do you need more tests?

Comment: I'll bow out here. Personally, I don't think these tests are valuable. You want integration tests here, but having extra tests on top don't give you any extra confidence.